# Rewriting CSS to SASS problem: same class definition in two css files

Tags: css, sass

I've been assigned to rewrite an existing CSS code into SASS. This is my first experience with SASS, still a beginner.

So, first thing that I started with, I merged all css files into single file. Now I'm going through it and try to separate things into different .scss files.

I have layouted my SASS folder's architecture according to "7-1" pattern, which consists of 7 folders: abstracts, base, layout, modules, pages, themes and vendors. So far so good.

In process of separating my CSS into different files I came across a problem that I couldn't find answers to on google:

Say I have 2 CSS files - main.css and admin.css. There is defined a class in main.css:

```
.first-line {
    padding-bottom:10px; 
    padding-left:30px;  
    padding-right:30px;
}
```

and a class with the same name is defined in admin.css

```
.first-line {
    padding-left:15x;  
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

As I understood from SASS tutorials online (correct me if I'm wrong), SASS code should result in only one main.scss where I import all particles, modules etc. and it get's compiled to single main.css file. If so, how do I solve a problem like this, where I need a class to be defined differently only for a single page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to nest that .first-line class in both the files (parent would be diff while nesting) ..... so while compiling into single file, it wont cause a problem

Answer (score 2):

If it is a single-page application, that means you have JavaScript in use.

You can simply define a unique class for each page and assign this class to either `body` or `html` element (I prefer the latter one), and in run time you can simply set the page class dynamically. This way, you can define the `first-line` class and set the default values and put it into a shared .scss file and then overwrite the existing attributes or add new ones to that class for each individual page as needed.

E.g., you might want to structure it like this.:

- `pages/common.scss`:

```css
first-line {
  padding-bottom:10px; 
  padding-left:30px;  
  padding-right:30px;
}
```

- `main.scss`:

```css
html {
  import 'pages/common';

  &.admin {
    @import 'pages/admin';
  }

  &.other-page {
    @import 'pages/other-page';
  }
}
```